# Get reputation changes across all sites without querying each one individually

Tags: support, feature-request, reputation

I'm looking to make an app that shows your reputation changes throughout the network. [`/me/reputation-history/full`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-full-reputation-history) almost accomplishes this, but it's on a per-site basis. I only want one query to get the last *x* changes over the whole network, like the new black topbar achievements dropdown does.

If there's a way to do this, it's [support](/questions/tagged/support). Otherwise, it's a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: So basically http://stackapps.com/topbar/achievements?

Comment: Exactly, @badp, but with less HTML and more API-ishness.

Answer (score 1):

One evening, after being inspired by [How to get (unread) achievements?](https://stackapps.com/q/8500/34061), I did some analysis with [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/). This was at a time that the publicly released version of the API was 2.2; it turned out that the Stack Exchange mobile apps use a (then) undocumented API v2.3 method for this: [`/me/achievements`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-achievements).

A `GET` call to `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/me/achievements?pageSize=100&filter=*-t3H1VAnvpZbcZ&access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]&key=[KEY]` yields the following result:

```json
{
    "quota_max": 10000,
    "quota_remaining": 7999,
    "has_more": false,
    "items": [
        {
            "achievement_type": "reputation",
            "account_id": 6085540,
            "reputation_change": 2,
            "is_unread": false,
            "link": "https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/130203/whats-the-best-way-to-combine-an-action-outside-of-the-ui-with-an-action-in-the/130208#130208",
            "creation_date": 1574444062,
            "title": "What&#39;s the best way to combine an action outside of the UI with an action in the UI?",
            "on_site": {
                "icon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ux/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
                "aliases": [
                    "http://ui.stackexchange.com"
                ],
                "site_url": "https://ux.stackexchange.com",
                "api_site_parameter": "ux",
                "name": "User Experience",
                "high_resolution_icon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ux/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png"
            }
        },
        {
            "achievement_type": "reputation",
            "account_id": 6085540,
            "reputation_change": 10,
            "is_unread": false,
            "link": "https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334137/dismiss-the-meet-the-overflow-and-podcast-episode-banners-network-wide/334202#334202",
            "creation_date": 1574443466,
            "title": "Dismiss the &quot;Meet The Overflow&quot; and Podcast Episode banners network-wide",
            "on_site": {
                "icon_url": "https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Sites/stackexchangemeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
                "site_url": "https://meta.stackexchange.com",
                "api_site_parameter": "meta",
                "name": "Meta Stack Exchange",
                "high_resolution_icon_url": "https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Sites/stackexchangemeta/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png"
            }
        },

...
```

It works with any Stack App token, not just the ones from the mobile apps. You'll probably need one with scope `read_inbox`, though I haven't tested that.

There's a related `GET` call to `https://mobile.stackexchange.com/1/push/topbar-counts?filter=vqc7J` which returns the number of unread inbox items and the total new reputation (the green `+x` badge), but it only works with a token which belongs to the mobile apps. It returns something like this:

```json
{
    "total": 1,
    "quota_max": 2147483647,
    "quota_remaining": 2147483647,
    "has_more": false,
    "page": 1,
    "type": "mobile_top_bar_counts",
    "items": [
        {
            "unread_inbox_count": 0,
            "account_id": 6085540,
            "unviewed_non_rep_count": 0,
            "unviewed_rep_count": 0
        }
    ],
    "page_size": 1
}
```

The `filter` seems to be necessary; without it, I get a backoff response.

Comment: It is also good to know that you need the "read_inbox" scope and the custom filter `*-t3H1VAnvpZbcZ` used for `2.3/me/achievements` does not contain all `site` information, otherwise it has all the other values ​​like the default filter.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "token which belongs to the mobile apps". Can ever one get such a token?

Comment: The official Stack Exchange mobile apps use the API as well. By analyzing network traffic (with something like mitmproxy) you can see which API methods they call but you can also extract the access token and key. It's not something you can rely on if you build apps for other users.