# How to get unread reputation changes via the API?

Tags: support, api, reputation

I want to write a desktop widget that checks the Stack Exchange API every several seconds and tells me if there are any new reputation changes. I can't figure out what API method I can use for that.

I tried [`/me/reputation-history/full`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-full-reputation-history#filter=default&site=stackoverflow), but it doesn't show which reputation changes are read or unread. I tried other methods as well, but none of them seem to do what I need.

Right now, I'm testing those methods with several unread reputation changes.

Comment: You currently cannot do this using only the API (version 2.2).  You can either  (1) track only what is read via your widget, or (2) use advanced bot techniques to simulate a fully logged-in, javascript-parsing, read of an appropriate SE page. (I don't recommend approach 2.) ... ... Consider rewriting this Q as a feature request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get reputation changes across all sites without querying each one individually](https://stackapps.com/questions/4808/get-reputation-changes-across-all-sites-without-querying-each-one-individually)