# How to get (unread) achievements?

Tags: support, api, reputation, badges

Is there an API call where you can get all achievements and all unread achievements?

Like this:

[image]

### Update

Thanks to the [answer](https://stackapps.com/a/8502/64628) of [Glorfindel](https://stackapps.com/users/34061/glorfindel), I use the following methods to calculate the unread achievements.

> Note: I'm using angular 8

notification.service.ts

```js
public getAchievements(options?: IQuestionOptions): Observable<IResponse> {   
  const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Accept', '*/*');

  const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('key', {{APP_KEY}})
    .set('access_token', {{TOKEN}})
    .set('pageSize', '30')
    .set('page', '1')
    .set('filter', 'O5lYbEN2lExNfdp2Q');

  return this.http
    .get<IResponse>(
      'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/', 
      { headers, params }
    );
}
```

Counting unread items

```js
public countUnread(items: any): number {
  if (!items) {
    return 0;
  }

  return items
    .map(item => item.is_unread ?
      item.reputation_change ?
        item.reputation_change
        : 1
      : 0)
    .reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue);
}
```

> Also to be mentioned is that this method is used for counting unread messages and unread achievements, depending on what was handed over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Badges and new privileges are part of the [/notifications](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/notifications) method, which is a single call for all accounts across the network. The results show whether the notification is unread or not. There's also a separate method just for unread notifications: [/notifications/unread](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/unread-notifications).
- For reputation changes, all I know are some site-specific methods ([/me/reputation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-reputation), [/me/reputation-history](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-reputation-history) and [/me/reputation-history/full](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-full-reputation-history)). They don't have a read/unread indication. There *must* be one which does, and provides a network-wide view, since the Stack Exchange mobile apps use them. This question is asking the same: [Get reputation changes across all sites without querying each one individually](https://stackapps.com/q/4808/34061) and I found the answer: it's an undocumented API v2.3 method, `/me/achievements`.

Comment: I also came across this question but this has not been answered for over 5 years. And is there a way to figure out how / where the 'Stack Exchange mobile apps' get the value for changed reputations?

Comment: I found the API method and from my tests you should be able to make it work. More details are in the linked question.